# Why won't custom events logged in Python show up in API Explorer?

Tags: python, azure, azure-application-insights, opencensus

For context, I am building a dashboard summarizing events, traces, and exceptions across multiple environments on Azure.

I am using the opencensus github project at 
https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-python/tree/master/contrib/opencensus-ext-azure

I am able to fetch and retrieve the customEvents logs, but only through the Azure portal.

[image: Azure Portal]

The API Explorer returns no data.

[image: API Explorer]

*For reference*

App Insights logging in JS and TS trackEvent has no issue. 
I cannot find any documentation on why this is happening nor how to query the logs outside of the Azure portal.

Comment: It seems as of now "to query the logs outside of the Azure portal" is not supported. You can refer to [Set up Azure Monitor for your Python application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python#telemetry-type-mappings) and [azure-monitor-opencensus-python](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-monitor-opencensus-python/blob/master/azure_monitor/python_logger_opencensus_azure/README.md). You can also open an issue on GitHub: [opencensus-python](https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-python/issues)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT that's really odd, where specifically is that quote from? it doesn't seem to be from either link?  the logs service used inside the azure portal would be the exact same service the one used by api explorer.

Comment: @raymond are you sure that the api explorer example is querying the exact same app insights resource/log analytics workspace?

Comment: @JohnGardner, yes I can confirm I am querying the exact same App Insights resource.